# How to Configure Magento 2 and Ngrok?

Tags: magento2

I want to access my local Magento server on public URL , I have created a shared link with `ngrook`, and it works, but all assets are with my test domain?

Tried database unsecure URL change, but then I get TOO MANY REDIRECTS.

Comment: I have answered the solution, but next time please be more informative.

Answer (score 1):

Update your base urls form `core_config_data` table.

- Url with http:

  `` UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://ngrok.io/your_url/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url'; ``
- Url with https:

  `` UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'https://ngrok.io/your_url/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/base_url'; ``
- Clear Magento Cache:

  `php bin/magento cache:flush`

**Another Solution For LEMP:**

Download ngrok for Linux/Ubuntu & check doc from https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/setup

```
cd /home/user/Downloads/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64
./ngrok http http://www.magento2.lan/
```

sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento2.lan

```
server {
          listen 80;
         # server_name www.magento2.lan;
          server_name 203fb3da8b95.ngrok.io;

          set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento2.lan;
          include /var/www/html/magento2.lan/nginx.conf.sample;

 }
```

sudo nano /etc/hosts:

> #127.0.0.1       [www.magento2.lan](http://www.magento2.lan)
> 127.0.0.1       203fb3da8b95.ngrok.io

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` where value like "%http%"
```

Change url

```
www.magento2.lan/ to 203fb3da8b95.ngrok.io
```

Clean cache u may run :

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/tmp/_cache var/composer_home/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* var/report/* var/log/* generated/code/*  pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/_cache/*
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: Have You tried this by Yourself, I told that changing this, cause me "Too many redirects" error

Comment: Yes. 
Kindly clear cache and try.
`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Check http://7eabc626.ngrok.io/ same as was.

Comment: Can you map a static file with ngrok and show me?

Comment: What do you mean static file with ngrok? Specify please

Comment: Just some HTML file. I think it's a ngrok issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86728/discussion-between-lolipopcoder-and-milind-singh).